# How can I count the records in an attribute?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Currently struggling a little with core data in ios and can't find an answer which is working in the current Swift version.
Is it anyhow possible to count the number of records in an attribute ?

```
let results = try managedContext.fetch(request)
print (results.count)
```

This is just giving me the results of all records in the entity but I need to know it from a single attribute.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "count the number of records in an attribute"? An attribute is a single value within the entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code, which will give count of records in the perticular attribute. I hope this will help you:

```
let fetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ENTITY")
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "ENTITY", in: managedObjectContextInstance)
let statusDesc = entity?.attributesByName["attribute_name"]

fetch.propertiesToFetch = [statusDesc].compactMap { $0 }
fetch.resultType = .dictionaryResultType

var results: [Any]? = [Any]()
do {
    results = try mainManagedObjectContextInstance.fetch(fetch)
} catch { 
}
print(results.count)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you edit your question to provide us with a little more information.

Without more information from you, this answer is provided following my ***best guess*** at attempting to interpret your question.

Some basic terminology to help out.

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/modeling_data?changes=_7) states that you...

> Model your data by describing your objects as entities, adding their
>   properties as attributes and relationships, and finally generating
>   respective NSManagedObject subclasses to inherit change tracking and
>   life cycle management.

Could I suggest your question might make more sense written as:

***Is it possible to count the number of records that match a certain value for an attribute?***

If my guess is correct, you could use the following code, noting that:

- the certain value is "attribute value to count"; and
- the attribute is "testAttribute".

  ```
  let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "TestEntity")

  let key = "testAttribute"                // the entity attribute
  let value = "attribute value to count"   // the attribute value

  let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", argumentArray: [key, value])

  request.predicate = predicate
  request.resultType = .countResultType

  var results: Int = 0

  do {

      results = try context.count(for: request)
  }
  catch {

      let fetchError = error
      print(fetchError)
  }
  ```

By specifiying an `NSFetchRequestResultType` as `.countResultType`, you're asking your fetch request to only count the number of managed objects for the specified entity that match the predicate (where "testAttribute" = "attribute value to count").

This is a very efficient fetch.

It **does not** fetch managed objects into memory 
(e.g. an array of `NSManagedObject` via `var results: [NSManagedObject]?`),

It **does** fetch only the count of managed objects into memory
(e.g. a count of `NSManagedObject` via `var results: Int = 0`).